# Angular: Detecting User Click in whole app

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events

I want to detect if user clicks anywhere (basically interacts with the application), in one of my child component.

The position or the component the user clicked in shouldn't matter, it should detect the click event in the whole app.

Anyway I would be able to do this?

Comment: I havent used angular since 1.0 but couldnt you just bind the event to javascripts window or window.document?

Comment: Using javascript document object is a bad practice in angular, it has it's own way of handling dom related things

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that. From what I remember Angular has a service you can inject that represents the equivalent of the document, correct? I would suggest using that unless something more appropriate has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) decorator:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
handlerFunction(e: MouseEvent) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@HostListener('window:click') click() {};` must be enough

Comment: My problem is I want to achieve this with a child compent, with this, it will only be able to detect changes in that component itself, not outside that component

Comment: if you put `@HostListener('window:click') click() {};` It will be effective on all the page!